# Conflict between tikz package qtree and tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree, neuralnetwork

I am writing my thesis manuscript and I have a conflict with the tikz packages. I made this artificial neural network and I get this result at the base (expected).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    %\usetikzlibrary{tikz}
    %\pagestyle{empty}

    \def\layersep{2.5cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
        \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
        \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
        \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
        \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
        \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
        \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

        % Draw the input layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
        % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
            \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y-4.5) {};

        % Draw the first hidden layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,6}
            \path[yshift=0.5cm]
                node[hidden neuron] (H1-\name) at (\layersep,-\y -4) {};


        % Draw the second hidden layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,6}
        \path[yshift=0.5cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H2-\name) at (3*\layersep,-\y -4) {};

        % Draw the output layer node
        %\node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-3] (O) {};

        % Draw the input layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
        % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
            \node[output neuron, pin=right:Output \#\y] (O-\name) at (4*\layersep,-\y -5.) {};

        % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
        % hidden layer.
        \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
            \foreach \dest in {1,...,6}
                \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);

        % Connect every node in the first HL with every node in the
        % second hidden layer.
        \foreach \source in {1,...,6}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,6}
            \path (H1-\source) edge (H2-\dest);


        % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
        \foreach \source in {1,...,6}
            %\path (H-\source) edge (O);
            \foreach \dest in {1,...,3}
                \path (H2-\source) edge (O-\dest);

        % Annotate the layers
        \node[annot,above of=H1-1, node distance=1cm] (hl1) {Hidden \\ layer};
        \node[annot,above of=H2-1, node distance=1cm] (hl2) {Hidden \\ layer};
        \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input\\layer};
        \node[annot,right of=hl2] {Output\\layer};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Example of a multilayers perceptron}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The expected result:

[image]

But recently I implemented some new tree-like figures for another part of the manuscrit, to get this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{font=\small,
    edge from parent fork down,
    level distance=1.3cm,
    every node/.style=
    {
        top color=white,
        bottom color=white,
        rectangle,rounded corners,
        minimum height=8mm,
        draw=black,
        very thick,
        drop shadow,
        align=center,
        text depth = 0pt
    },
    edge from parent/.style=
        {
            draw=black,
            thick
        }}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.{Deep learning\\techniques in time series}
            [.{Artificial Neural\\Network} ] 
            [.{Recurrent Neural\\Network}
                [.{Long Short\\Term Memory} 
                    [.{Gated Recurrent\\Unit} ]
                ]
            ]
    ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Global deep learning techniques for anomaly detection in times series}
    \label{fig:Global deep learning techniques for anomaly detection in times series}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But in the end I have several problems that I can't solve:

- The nodes are not the same size.
- The lines of the qtree are not vertical and horizontal.
- The neural network has no color .
- The names of the layers exceed the nodes.

[image]

[image]

it's like there is a conflict between packets, or do I need tags to specify which packet to use in which place? I don't know because I never had this case.

Here the complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}


\begin{document}

\tikzset{font=\small,
    edge from parent fork down,
    level distance=1.3cm,
    every node/.style=
    {
        top color=white,
        bottom color=white,
        rectangle,rounded corners,
        minimum height=8mm,
        draw=black,
        very thick,
        drop shadow,
        align=center,
        text depth = 0pt
    },
    edge from parent/.style=
        {
            draw=black,
            thick
        }}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.{Deep learning\\techniques in time series}
            [.{Artificial Neural\\Network} ] 
            [.{Recurrent Neural\\Network}
                [.{Long Short\\Term Memory} 
                    [.{Gated Recurrent\\Unit} ]
                ]
            ]
    ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Global deep learning techniques for anomaly detection in times series}
    \label{fig:Global deep learning techniques for anomaly detection in times series}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[h!]
    %\usetikzlibrary{tikz}
    %\pagestyle{empty}

    \def\layersep{2.5cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
        \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
        \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
        \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
        \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
        \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
        \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

        % Draw the input layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
        % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
            \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y-4.5) {};

        % Draw the first hidden layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,6}
            \path[yshift=0.5cm]
                node[hidden neuron] (H1-\name) at (\layersep,-\y -4) {};


        % Draw the second hidden layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,6}
        \path[yshift=0.5cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H2-\name) at (3*\layersep,-\y -4) {};

        % Draw the output layer node
        %\node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-3] (O) {};

        % Draw the input layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
        % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
            \node[output neuron, pin=right:Output \#\y] (O-\name) at (4*\layersep,-\y -5.) {};

        % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
        % hidden layer.
        \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
            \foreach \dest in {1,...,6}
                \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);

        % Connect every node in the first HL with every node in the
        % second hidden layer.
        \foreach \source in {1,...,6}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,6}
            \path (H1-\source) edge (H2-\dest);


        % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
        \foreach \source in {1,...,6}
            %\path (H-\source) edge (O);
            \foreach \dest in {1,...,3}
                \path (H2-\source) edge (O-\dest);

        % Annotate the layers
        \node[annot,above of=H1-1, node distance=1cm] (hl1) {Hidden \\ layer};
        \node[annot,above of=H2-1, node distance=1cm] (hl2) {Hidden \\ layer};
        \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input\\layer};
        \node[annot,right of=hl2] {Output\\layer};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Example of a multilayers perceptron}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please create a Minimal Working Example showing the conflict. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tree:

- Where is defined `edge from parent fork down`?
- For use `drop shadow` you need to load Ti*k*Z library `shadows`.

Neural network:

- For placement of neuron nodes is used `chains` library
- Rewritten are picture elements styles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains, 
                positioning,
                shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
    {draw,
     edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
                            -- +(0,-8pt)
                            -| (\tikzchildnode)}
     },
    level distance=17mm, sibling distance = 11mm,
    every node/.style=
    {draw, very thick, rounded corners, fill=white,
     font=\small,
     minimum height=8mm, text width=8em, %text depth=0pt,
     align=center,
     drop shadow,
    }
            }
\Tree [.{Deep learning techniques in\\ time series}
        [.{Artificial\\ Neural Network} ]
        [.{Recurrent\\ Neural Network}
            [.{Long Short Term Memory}
                [.{Gated\\ Recurrent Unit} ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Global deep learning techniques for anomaly detection in times series}
    \label{fig:Global deep learning techniques for anomaly detection in times series}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->, draw=black!50,
        node distance = 6mm and 24mm,
          start chain = going below,
every pin edge/.style = {<-,shorten <=1pt},
        neuron/.style = {circle, fill=#1,
                         minimum size=17pt, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt,
                         on chain},
         annot/.style = {draw, rounded corners, text width=4em, align=center}
                        ]
% Draw the input layer nodes
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \node[neuron=green!50,
          pin=180:Input \#\i] (I-\i)    {};
% Draw the hidden layers nodes
    \node[neuron=blue!50,
          above right=8mm and 24mm of I-1] (H-11)     {};
% first hide layer
\foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {2,...,6}
    \node[neuron=blue!50,
          below=of H-1\j]      (H-1\i)    {};

% second hide layer
\foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {1,...,6}
    \node[neuron=blue!50,
          right=of H-1\j]      (H-2\i)    {};

% Draw the output layer node
    \node[neuron=red!50,
          pin= {[pin edge=->]0:Output \#1},
          right=of $(H-22)!0.5!(H-23)$]  (O-1)   {};
\foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {2,3}
    \node[neuron=red!50,
          pin= {[pin edge=->]0:Output \#\j},
          below=of O-\j]        (O-\i)  {$x_{\i}$};
% Connect input nodes with hidden nodes and
%  hiden nodes with output nodes with the output layer
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,6}
{
    \path (I-\i) edge (H-1\j);
}
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,6}
{
    \path (H-1\i) edge (H-2\j);
}
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,3}
{
    \path (H-2\i) edge (O-\j);
}
% Annotate layers
\node[annot,above=of I-1 |- H-11.center]  {Hidden layer};
\node[annot,above=of H-11.center]         {Input layer};
\node[annot,above=of H-21.center]         {Input layer};
\node[annot,above=of O-1 |- H-21.center]  {Output layer};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Example of a multilayers perceptron}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
To have different width of nodes in Qtree, the simplest solution is change its preamble so, that `text width` replace with `minimum width` and text in nodes break manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains,
                positioning,
                shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
    {draw,
     edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
                            -- +(0,-8pt)
                            -| (\tikzchildnode)}
     },
    level distance=17mm, sibling distance = 8mm,      
    every tree node/.style=
    {draw, very thick, rounded corners, fill=white,
     font=\small,
     minimum height=8mm, minimum width=8em, align=center,
     drop shadow,
     anchor=north
    }
            }
\Tree [.{Deep learning techniques\\ in time series}
        [.{Artificial\\ Neural Network} ]
        [.{Recurrent\\ Neural Network}
            [.{Long Short\\ Term Memory}
                [.{Gated\\ Recurrent Unit} ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Global deep learning techniques for anomaly detection in times series}
    \label{fig:Global deep learning techniques for anomaly detection in times series}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead `tikz-qtree` package I would rather use `forest`. It is dedicated to draw trees and is very powerful. Using it the code for your tree is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{forest}
for tree={          
%% style of nodes 
 draw, rounded corners, 
       font = \small,
/tikz/align = flush center,%
   if level = {0}{text width=11em}{text width=7em},
       fill = white,
drop shadow = {shadow xshift=2mm, shadow yshift=-2mm},
%% style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
       grow = south,
    forked edge,      % for forked edge
      s sep = 5mm,    % sibling distance
      l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
   fork sep = 4mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
           }% end for tree
[Deep learning techniques in time series
    [Artificial Neural Network]
    [Recurrent Neural Network
        [Long Short Term Memory
            [Gated Recurrent Unit]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
    \caption{Global deep learning techniques for anomaly detection in times series}
    \label{fig:Global deep learning techniques for anomaly detection in times series}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: okay i understand for about my problem and how can I change the root to have a different shape from the others nodes ?

Comment: @ThonyNadhir, define new style for this noges. For more help please ask new question, where explain what is your new problem, It is not clear (to mee) what you mean with "root" ...

Comment: it's the node "deep learning techniques in times series". Is it possible to change its size?

Comment: @ThonyNadhir, in principle yes, but I must look in package documentation (I'm not very familiar with tikz-tree package) . OK, see addendum to answer. With forest if this can be an option, is simple. )also added to addendum). BTW, your problem has nothing common with Overleaf, your problem as well proposed solutions are the same in any LaTeX distribution. Therefore it should be deleted from tags.

Answer (score 2):

To make your code compilable, I remove `edge from parent fork down,` and then `drop shadow,`.

I notice you have

```
\tikzset{
...
every node/.style=
top color=white,
bottom color=white,
...
}}
```

That sets options for all following TikZ pictures. -and then all nodes in these. `top color` and `bottom color` is used to make a vertical shading, so it does not even make sense to set them both to white. Remove these two lines, and it compiles to give:

[image: A tree structure and a colored graph]

`\tikzset` is only used for options that is needed for all following TikZ pictures. Options for only one picture is given directly within `[..]` after `\begin{tikzpicture}` e.g. like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
```